# convert a .bat file to .sh a file

Tags: batch-file, sh

i have a .bat file to install outlook signatures on a windows pc.

this is the text the .bat file has:

```
xcopy /s /I /C /F /R /Y sig_files\* "%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures\"
```

can anyone help me convert this .bat file to a .sh file?

Comment: For what purpose? Running it on a UNIX system without Outlook? Running it on Windows via Cygwin?

Answer (score 0):

The linux command that is roughly eqivalent to `XCOPY` is `cp`. You can type `man cp` on the linux command line to get help on the flags (which are going to be preceded by a `-` rather than a `/`. `man cp` is the equivalent of `help xcopy`.

Comment: so i should write?

cp -s -I -C -F -R -Y sig_files\* "%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures\"

Comment: i am not sure. is it? i really don't develop on a Linux machine so this is new to me. sorry.